# How to get hardware device serial number with help of ip address?

Tags: java

Is there any method to get serial number of hardware device within the same network with the help of the ip address?

Comment: Do you mean MAC address?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.55");
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
  if (ni != null) {
     byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
     sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
     }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the MAC address of the network adapter, you can use the NetworkInterface class to obtain the MAC

```
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.1");
    NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
    if (ni != null) {
         byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Hyperic SIGAR API :**
Hyperic's System Information Gatherer (SIGAR) is a cross-platform API for collecting software inventory data. SIGAR includes support for Linux, FreeBSD, Windows, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX and Mac OSX across a variety of versions and architectures. Users of the SIGAR API are given portable access to inventory and monitoring data including:

1. System memory, swap, cpu, load average, uptime, logins.
2. Per-process memory, cpu, credential info, state, arguments, environment, open files.
3. File system detection and metrics.
4. Network interface detection, configuration information and metrics.
5. Network route and connection tables.

The core API is implemented in pure C with bindings currently implemented for Java, Perl and C#.

**For more information about download & API:** [Hyperic SIGAR API](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar)

**Using VBS :**

**MotherBoard Serial Number :**

```
String vbs =
     "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
    + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
    + "   (\"Select * from Win32_BaseBoard\") \n"
    + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
    + "    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber \n"
    + "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n"
    + "Next \n";
```

**HDD Serial Number :**

```
String vbs = "Set objFSO = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\")\n"
              +"Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives\n"
              +"Set objDrive = colDrives.item(\"" + drive + "\")\n"
              +"Wscript.Echo objDrive.SerialNumber";  // see note
```

For **Example Demo :** [Get the hard disk serial number or Motherboard serial number](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0580.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "serial number" in this case the MAC address of the device, at a command prompt/shell:

```
ping <ip>
arp -a
```

And you will get a list of MAC <-> IP mappings.  This will work on both Windows, MacOS and Linux.

You could run these commands though `Runtime.exec()` and parse the output, but note that the format of the output is different depending on OS.